# Gradient Descent isn't working

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, gradient-descent, non-linear-regression

I am learning tensorflow from a Stanford course named, "TensorFlow for Deep Learning Research". I have taken the code from the following [address](https://github.com/chiphuyen/tf-stanford-tutorials/blob/master/examples/03_linear_regression_sol.py). While exploring tensorflow I changed

Y_predicted = X * w + b

as

Y_predicted = ​ X ​* ​ X ​* ​ w ​+ ​ X ​* ​ u ​+ ​ b

to check that non-linear curve fitted better. I have added

Y_predicted ​= ​ X ​* ​ X ​* ​ w ​+ ​ X ​* ​ u ​+ ​ b

according to author's suggestion of this [note(page 3)](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/lectures/notes_03.pdf). But after adding this line and run the similar code again, every error value seems to get **nan**.
Can anybody point out the problem and give a solution.

```
""" Simple linear regression example in TensorFlow
This program tries to predict the number of thefts from 
the number of fire in the city of Chicago
Author: Chip Huyen
Prepared for the class CS 20SI: "TensorFlow for Deep Learning Research"
cs20si.stanford.edu
"""
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import xlrd

#import utils

DATA_FILE = "slr05.xls"

# Step 1: read in data from the .xls file
book = xlrd.open_workbook(DATA_FILE, encoding_override="utf-8")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
data = np.asarray([sheet.row_values(i) for i in range(1, sheet.nrows)])
n_samples = sheet.nrows - 1

# Step 2: create placeholders for input X (number of fire) and label Y (number of theft)
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y')

# Step 3: create weight and bias, initialized to 0
w = tf.Variable(0.0, name='weights')
u = tf.Variable(0.0, name='weights2')
b = tf.Variable(0.0, name='bias')

# Step 4: build model to predict Y
#Y_predicted = X * w + b 
Y_predicted = X ​* ​ X ​* ​ w ​+ ​ X ​* ​ u ​+ ​ b

# Step 5: use the square error as the loss function
loss = tf.square(Y - Y_predicted, name='loss')
# loss = utils.huber_loss(Y, Y_predicted)

# Step 6: using gradient descent with learning rate of 0.01 to minimize loss
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Step 7: initialize the necessary variables, in this case, w and b
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/linear_reg', sess.graph)

    # Step 8: train the model
    for i in range(100): # train the model 100 epochs
        total_loss = 0
        for x, y in data:
            # Session runs train_op and fetch values of loss
            _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={X: x, Y:y}) 
            total_loss += l
        print('Epoch {0}: {1}'.format(i, total_loss/n_samples))

    # close the writer when you're done using it
    writer.close() 

    # Step 9: output the values of w and b
    w, u , b = sess.run([w, u , b]) 

# plot the results
X, Y = data.T[0], data.T[1]
plt.plot(X, Y, 'bo', label='Real data')
plt.plot(X, X * x * w + X * u + b, 'r', label='Predicted data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops! Your learning rate seems too big, try with something like `learning_rate=0.0000001` and it will converge. This is a common problem, especially when you introduce *interaction features*, as in your case: you should keep in mind that the range of `x**2` will be greater (if the original was [-100, 100] the quadratic will be [-10000, 10000]), hence the learning rate that worked well for the linear model may be too big for the polynomial one. Check out about [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). This picture gives a more intuitive explanation:

[image]

Hope it helps!
Andres

Comment: Now I understand what was the problem. Thank you for pointing out. Setting the gradient 0.00000001 gives around error 739 which is better than previous Linear basis function. After plotting I got the following output, http://imgur.com/7RwnfvD Why there is multiple red line? Is this happening for Basis function expansion(as the data is in higher dimension)

Comment: Hi! this seems like a plotting issue... you should see a single parabolic line, the one corresponding to your optimized w, u and b parameters you can try it in WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E2%2B3x%2B4

Have fun with TF!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the person teaching that course. Like @fr_andres said, your lr is probably too big. Let me know if that doesn't work.